# Angular 2 Renderer2 prependChild-like behavior

Tags: angular

How can I insert a new child as the first child of a parent using Angular 2' Renderer2?

Given `<div> <span>Foobar</span> </div>` I want to insert an element before the `span` so it becomes `<div> <span>New element</span> <span>Foobar</span> </div>`.

Problem is that I only have access to the containing div and I cannot figure out how to either 'prepend' the new element (as jQuery can/would do it), or find the first child element of the parent so that I can use `insertBefore` from the renderer.

I tried using `ContentChild` to get the first element, but it gives `null`, and I guess that it because this is all going on in a *directive* and I don't know the content of the native element.

Usage is this; a directive that adds an icon tag as the first child of an element, eg `<button myIconDirective>Foobar</button>` should become `<button myIconDirective><i class="icon-classes"></i>Foobar</button>`.

Here's a plunker to tinker with, the +'s are currently at the wrong side of the text :) http://plnkr.co/edit/mknH3yeTnFpepaIwmHUN

Comment: need a plunker to experiment

Comment: @Maximus added it

Answer (score 17):

It doesn't seem to be possible without falling back on using native node `firstChild` child reference:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const newElement = this.renderer.createElement('i');
    this.renderer.insertBefore(this.el.nativeElement, newElement, this.el.nativeElement.firstChild); 
}
```

And [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UOQNbJF7IE8bzoB3kBc8?p=preview)

Comment: That means this would break during server-side rendering right?

Comment: I don't know, this needs to be tested

Comment: ok, but you should test the solution in server side rendering, I'm not sure it will break

Comment: This is what I'm using in SSR: renderer.insertBefore(document.head, comment, document.head.children.item(0));